# Decoding Hex Data

Tags: decryption, hex

I'm trying to decode `.PLW` data acquired by a temperature logger ([PicoLog PT-104](https://www.picotech.com/download/manuals/usb-pt104-rtd-data-logger-programmers-guide.pdf)).

If you convert the `.PLW` file to a `.txt` file through the official software you get something like this:

[image]

where each row has single temperature measurements across the 20 channels available to the device. I would like to extract the data directly from the `.PLW`, file without having to convert it to `.txt` first.

By opening the `.PLW` file in a hex editor, I have managed to isolate with a bit of tweaking the section which seems to contain the raw data measurements:

[image: hex_dump]

The first 4 hexes contain the row index. And should be read in the reversed column order `03 02 01 00`.

There are then the 20 groups of 4 columns, one for each channel. Assuming all groups should be read right to left (given that was the case for the index columns), they all seem to begin with `0x41` which might maybe be some kind of encoding for the tab character (or similar).

The next hex in each chunk (so the one just before the `0x41`) seems to be mapping at least to some approximate way the temperature read in that channel:

- Hex -> TEMP
- `0x50 -> 13`
- `0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3 -> 20`
- `0xa4, 0xa5, 0xaa, 0xab -> 21`
- `0xac, 0xae, 0xb0 -> 22`

And the order of the channels also seems to match the order of the columns in the `.txt` file: for example channel 8 in the `.txt` file has an outlier temperature at `13` --> which is also present in the 8th data column in the `.PLW` file, where the *temperature* hex is set to `0x50`

Would anyone be able to crack the mapping between the hex values in each chunk to the final temperature measurement displayed in the `.txt` file?

Or does anyone know of an encoding where `0x41` would correspond to a tab-like character? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data are floating point encoded on 32 bits Little_endian
byte 0 to 3: 00 00 00 00 = 0 channel number
byte 4 to 7: 1f 85 a3 41 = 0x41a3851f = 20.4400005341
etc ..
https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Just for the record, bytes 0 to 3 are the measurement index number. The following 20 * 4-byte encoded values are the temperature values from each channel.

Thanks again Gordon!

Comment: I would be very interested to get my hands on a couple of these .PLW files. Could you post a couple or point to a good resource?